# How do you define the size of an image that is a php variable that is called for an html table

Tags: php, html, image, variables

I am trying to pull images from a database into an html table as a php variable:

```
<img src=img/$image&w=100&h=150>
```

the image does not show, but everything else in the table pertaining to the product shows

If I change the code adding a space after the variable:

```
<img src=img/$image &w=100&h=150>
```

The images show but they are very large.

How do I get $image to show at w=100 and h=150 within the table?

Thanks!!

Comment: please post what both cases produce on the website

Comment: Have you tried `<img src=img/{$image}?w=100&h=150>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out:

CODE:

```
<img src='img/$image' class='scale-down' style='width:100px;height:150px'>
```

CSS:

```
  .scale-down {
    object-fit: scale-down;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code below doesn't work for some reason, be sure you linked your CSS file.

CODE:

```
<img src='img/$image' class='scale-down'> <!-- Removed style attribute --!>
```

CSS:

```
  .scale-down {
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    }
```

Another interesting point is if you want to you the object-fit then you can. Meaning you would have the images contained by the size of the elements you are putting them in. Therefore, you should be defining the width & height of the element that contains the images and then you can do as you did:
In this example I wrote `td` but I don't know what element contains your images so be sure to change it, if it is different.

```
td {
width:100px;
height:150px;
}

.scale-down {
object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

If your aim is to learn web-development then you should also be thinking about the client as kerbholz rightly points out:

> Probably. Scaling down an image via CSS/style isn't a performant solution though, clients would still need to transfer for example a 1920x1080 image only to scale it down to 100x150. Anyway. – kerbholz

Please be aware that many questions about web development have already been answered here and on the web. Good luck!

The following are links to CSS, these websites have a lot more than just CSS.
MDN is really useful if you want to know more: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS
W3 is also useful but they don't always do as good of a job:
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/

Comment: Mdn won't. `w=100&h=150` _might_ be dimensions to return a resized image, we don't know OPs setup

Comment: It’s true we don’t. But given the lack of information I’ve provided a solution that will *probably* work.

Comment: Probably. Scaling down an image via CSS/style isn't a performant solution though, clients would still need to transfer for example a 1920x1080 image only to scale it down to 100x150. Anyway.